# Search and get the inner most keys in a deeply nested dictionary without for loop?

Tags: python

I have an arbitrary nested python dict, as such;

```
{u'1009': {u'2017': {u'April': {
    u'Revenue': 35837,
    u'Total_users': 107,
    u'Unique_users': 79},
   u'August': {
    u'Revenue': 98958,
    u'Total_users': 314,
    u'Unique_users': 208},
   u'December': {
    u'Revenue': 123334,
    u'Total_users': 440,
    u'Unique_users': 241}},
  u'2018': {u'April': {
    u'Revenue': 4280,
    u'Total_users': 13,
    u'Unique_users': 12},
   u'February': {
    u'Revenue': 88922,
    u'Total_users': 354,
    u'Unique_users': 205},
   u'January': {
    u'Revenue': 183031,
    u'Total_users': 429,
    u'Unique_users': 239},
   u'March': {
    u'Revenue': 101068,
    u'Total_users': 359,
    u'Unique_users': 222}}
u'1051': {u'2017': {u'August': {
    u'Revenue': 10450,
    u'Total_users': 40,
    u'Unique_users': 26},
   u'July': {
    u'Revenue': 38980,
    u'Total_users': 132,
    u'Unique_users': 42},
   u'June': {
    u'Revenue': 15820,
    u'Total_users': 54,
    u'Unique_users': 36}}}}
```

In the above dictionary, the outermost keys are changing, but the innermost key (Revenue,etc) aren't. If i need to locate the top 5 Revenue values, i need to use a multiple for loops and also store value. Is there any elegant way to skip a level of keys and/or directly search the inner most keys in a nested dict?

Example code:

```
for key_1 in a:
    for key_2 in a[key_1]:
        for key_3 in a[key_1][key_2]:
            print {key_3:a[key_1][key_2][key_3]['Revenue']}
```

Comment: I added the example, but an o(n)3 solution is very bad for performance if i'm looking at a huge dictionary

Comment: It's not O(n^3). It's looping over each entry once, so if *n* is the number of entries at any level then it's O(n). It can be written more elegantly, perhaps, but that's as fast as you're going to get.